# is there anything like $view_mode in user-profile.tpl.php

Tags: 7, theming, users

in node.tpl.php you have variable $view_mode, is there anythings like that in user-profile.tpl.php?
user is bundle like node, and you can define different view modes for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is. There *should* be, and if I had to guess I'd say there *will* be in D8. Large parts of the entity api simply didn't get implemented in D7, and nodes were probably just considered a higher priority.

I believe the [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) modules work by extending the user entity, it may provide you with what you want.
Otherwise my suggestion is [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels), which can control the user view via something called "Selection rules", instead of view modes.

Comment: $variables['elements']['#view_mode'] is what I found

Comment: That's great, but can you actually change it? :) Perhaps [display suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) can do that.

Comment: simply with hook_entity_info_alter